# sort associative multi array by key value

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

below is my array , i want to sort in by price in asc order.

i wrote below code

```
Array
(
    [105493] => Array
        (
            [info] => Array
                (
                    [price] => $50.00
                    [hazmat] => Not Required
                )
        )

    [105494] => Array
        (
            [info] => Array
                (
                    [price] => $93.60
                    [hazmat] => Not Required
                )

        )

    [105495] => Array
        (
            [info] => Array
                (
                    [price] => $198.00
                    [hazmat] => Not Required
                )
        )

    [105496] => Array
        (
            [info] => Array
                (
                    [price] => $662.00
                    [hazmat] => Not Required
                )
        )
)
```

i worte below code to sort it

```
function customer_sort ($a, $b) {

    if ($a['info']['price'] == $b['info']['price']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $a['info']['price'] > $b['info']['price'] ? 1 : -1;
}
uasort($assc_product_data, 'customer_sort');
```

but my code is not woking fine how can i solve issue

Comment: Why not use built in php functions for sorting arrays ?

Comment: @Maximus2012 Uhhh like which one for this?

Comment: @Maximus2012 There's no built-in function that sorts by a field nested 2 levels down in the array.

Comment: Do you really have `$` at the beginning of your prices? You need to remove that before you can compare them as numbers.

Comment: @Barmar Maybe he wrote his own C function and recompiled everything :)

Comment: @Rizier123 I wish I could do that !

Comment: @user1799722 yes, $ is symbol for USD, but $ also makes that variable a *string*, which makes it difficult to compare the values as *numbers*

Comment: return `strnatcmp()` based on your criteria.

Comment: Do not store formatted data and expect to be able to sort it.  Specifically, store money as 5000.00 in your array, not $5,000.00 then format it as needed on your output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the `$` before comparing the prices:

```
function customer_sort($a, $b)
    if ($a['info']['price'] == $b['info']['price']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return substr($a['info']['price'], 1) > substr($b['info']['price'], 1) ? 1 : -1;
}
```

You could also use the built-in function [`strnatcmp`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strnatcmp.php):

```
function customer_sort($a, $b) {
    return strnatcmp($a['info']['price'], $b['info']['price']);
}
```